# Azure App Service Linux hosting Wordpress error "Installing WordPress ... This could be done in minutes. Please refresh your browser later."

Tags: php, wordpress, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am hosting my blog on Azure App Service platform on the new linux host.It was working fine but now the website cannot be accessed and it is giving error "Installing WordPress ... This could be done in minutes. Please refresh your browser later." This stays like that for for ever.

I checked the health  and everything is fine.I tried to enable php loggiong by editing the  wp-config.php by adding these two lines

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

But I do not see the the log file generated.Accessing the  phpmyadmin gives error

```
"No route registered for '/phpmyadmin/'"
```

This msdn  [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/21/create-wordpress-using-web-apps-on-linux/) says that I might have to upgrade my docker image.I have some blog already created,I would like to create a export the DB before doing anything.

I have also added the .user.ini file with log_errors=on but do not see any errors logged.

**edit:**

Here's the error from docket_XX_err.log file:

```
2017-04-21T03:06:06.663993010Z AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
2017-04-21T03:06:14.616897475Z ERROR 1102 (42000) at line 1: Incorrect database name ''
2017-04-21T04:06:56.519319746Z AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
2017-04-21T04:07:00.414460896Z ERROR 1102 (42000) at line 1: Incorrect database name ''
```

** edit 2**

updating the docker image to appsvc/apps:wordpress:0.1 shown below did not fix the problem.

[image: dockerimage update]

The error in the docker_XX log says

```
Digest: sha256:ca50223ff969665a64ed3b690124f56d1cc51754331e94baa80327dcc474c020
Status: Image is up to date for appsvc/apps:wordpress
wordpress: Pulling from appsvc/apps
Digest: sha256:ca50223ff969665a64ed3b690124f56d1cc51754331e94baa80327dcc474c020
Status: Image is up to date for appsvc/apps:wordpress
wordpress: Pulling from appsvc/apps
```

After updating the image ,am still not able to access phpmyadmin to export my data.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Using KUDU with Microsoft Azure Web Apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/)

> we can cat log by kudu, just like that: navigate to
>   **https://*****.scm.azurewebsites.net** where ***** is the name of your
>   Web App.

2. LogFiles location with kudu

> Debug console=> Bash=> LogFiles

we can find error msg from `*****.log files(e.g. cat docker/docker_*****_err.log).`
could you post your log here? thanks

Comment: added the log  entries to the post

Comment: sorry for the delay. usually, we can get startup log from here: **/home/LogFiles/docker/docker_xx_err.log**. if the log is useless, we can access here: **/home/LogFiles/error_xx.log**

Answer (score 0):

Check your app settings. If they are using WORDPRESS_x, then they are using the older settings. You will have to change this.

Try updating the App Settings as per the new ones documented here:
https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/apps/blob/master/Wordpress/README.md#deploying--running

You may also need to update the docker image name through portal to use **appsvc/apps:wordpress-0.1**

Answer (score 0):

Got this from Microsoft support.

First FTP into the current Azure web app, and take a backup of the file content, specifically the “MySQL” folder.

Go to the Application Settings blade of your web app, and update the “Key” Names with the names as suggested in the following document:
https://github.com/Azure-App-Service/apps/blob/master/Wordpress/README.md

Now, go to the Docker Container blade and update the “Image and Optional tag” value to – “appsvc/apps:wordpress-0.1”

Once you do this you can access the phpmyadmin for your web app and get a backup of the database for your current WordPress web app by going to the following URL: yourwebappname.azurewebsites.net/phpmyadmin.